# How do I import my character from Mixamo into Blender with animation included?

Tags: animation

Oh boy. I cant get it to work.

Is there a good tutorial on this topic?

Comment: Download the fbx with skin from mixamo.com, then import it in the file>import>fbx menu.

Comment: Got it. Had issues downloading it but now for no reason it works...